# SQL Server get latest value by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server table that has project_id int,update_date datetime ,update_text varchar(max)

The table has many updates per project_id. I need to fetch the latest by update_date for all project_id values.

Example:

```
project_id    update_date    update_text
1             2017/01/01     Happy new year.
2             2017/01/01     Nice update
2             2017/02/14     Happy Valentine's
3             2016/12/25     Merry Christmas
3             2017/01/01     A New year is a good thing
```

The query should get:

```
project_id    update_date    update_text
1             2017/01/01     Happy new year.
2             2017/02/14     Happy Valentine's
3             2017/01/01     A New year is a good thing
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

using [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
select top 1 with ties
  project_id, update_date, update_text
from projects
order by row_number() over (partition by project_id order by update_date desc)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MGUNU86353

returns:

```
+------------+-------------+----------------------------+
| project_id | update_date |        update_text         |
+------------+-------------+----------------------------+
|          1 | 2017-01-01  | Happy new year.            |
|          2 | 2017-02-14  | Happy Valentine's          |
|          3 | 2017-01-01  | A New year is a good thing |
+------------+-------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Beat me to it! This is the correct answer. Partition by project_id and ordering by date desc is the best way to answer this kind of multiple id/audit type of data.

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you the latest date for each project

```
Select Project_Id, Max (Update_Date) Max_Update_Date
From MyTable
Group By Project_Id
```

So join it back to the original table

```
Select Project_Id, Update_Date, Update_Text
From MyTable
Inner Join
(
    Select Project_Id, Max (Update_Date) Max_Update_Date
    From MyTable
    Group By Project_Id
) MaxDates
On MyTable.Project_Id = MaxDates.Project_Id
And MyTable.Update_Date = MaxDates.Max_Update_Date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `MAX(date)` like:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] 
INNER JOIN (SELECT project_id, date = MAX(update_date) FROM [table] GROUP BY project_id) AS a
ON [table].project_id = a.project_id AND update_date = date
```

or you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY project_id ORDER BY 
update_date DESC) FROM [table]
) AS a WHERE rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note to top answer**:

Whilst some may say it is the best answer it will often not be the most efficient query time. In my data the following example is an order of magnitude faster.

`SELECT 
   project_id, update_date, update_text 
FROM 
   projects P 
WHERE 
   update_date = (SELECT MAX(update_date) FROM projects WHERE project_id = P.project_id)`

(If you can have more than one update on a given date then would need max on update_text and group by as in this specific example you would not know which update_text value was valid.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
with CTE as(
SELECT project_id,    MAX(update_date) update_date
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY project_id
    )

SELECT  cte.project_id,    cte.update_date , max(t.update_text) update_text
FROM YourTable T inner join CTE on T.project_id = CTE.project_id
group by cte.project_id,    cte.update_date ;
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/BYVTG40532)**.

Comment: This would give you an error, you have `MAX(update_date)` and `GROUP BY project_id` but `update_text` is missing an aggregation.