# SQL DB structure for N items with M parameters varying over time

Tags: sql, database, database-design

There're the items:

- `item_1`
- ...
- `item_N`

N is about a few hundreds. New items can be added sometimes.

Each item has a set of parameters:

- `parameter_1`
- ...
- `parameter_M`

M is about 20-30. These parameters are measured several times a day (independently of each other, in different time) and need to be stored in a database. So `parameter_j(item_i)` has a massive of time-value pairs:

- `<t0, v0>` (the first measurement of parameter_j(item_i))
- ...
- `<tk, vk>` (the latest measurement of parameter_j(item_i))

Base queries that need to be performed:

- all values of a parameter for an item (ordered by the time of measurement)
- the latest values of all parameters for all items

What database structure (tables) do I need to perform these quesries **efficiently**? Could you please provide SQL code for these two types of queries?

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions. As it stands this almost seems like an out sourcing job of 'Here's some specifications, write this code for me please'.

Comment: Ask 1 question per post. Re design: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. Quote the definitions, theorems & algorithms you are relying on. All the steps are also SO faqs. Re code: Show what you are able to do & give a [mre]. [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go with a structure like this:

[image: Structure of tables]

I will provide MS SQL codes.

Example code for creating these tables:

```
IF NOT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Items') IS NULL DROP TABLE #Items
CREATE TABLE #Items (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    ItemName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)

IF NOT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Measurements') IS NULL DROP TABLE #Measurements
CREATE TABLE #Measurements (
    ItemID int NOT NULL,
    MeasurementDate datetime NOT NULL,
    Param1 varchar(255),
    Param2 float,
    Param3 varchar(255),
    ParamN binary
    FOREIGN KEY (ItemID) REFERENCES #Items (ID)
)
```

I filled up with dummy data via this code:

```
INSERT INTO #Items values ( 0, 'Item1' )
INSERT INTO #Items values ( 1, 'Item2' )

INSERT INTO #Measurements (ItemID, MeasurementDate, Param2) values (0, GetDate(), 2.3)

INSERT INTO #Measurements (ItemID, MeasurementDate, Param3) values (1, DATEADD(day, 3, GetDate()), 'red')

INSERT INTO #Measurements (ItemID, MeasurementDate, Param3) values (1, DATEADD(day, 2, GetDate()), 'blue')

INSERT INTO #Measurements (ItemID, MeasurementDate, Param2) values (0, DATEADD(day, 5, GetDate()), 4.0)
```

**Query for ,,all values of a parameter for an item (ordered by the time of measurement)":**

Code:

```
SELECT #Measurements.MeasurementDate, #Measurements.Param2
FROM #Measurements INNER JOIN #Items ON #Measurements.ItemID = #Items.ID
WHERE #Items.ItemName LIKE '%Item1%'
ORDER BY #Measurements.MeasurementDate
```

Output:

[image]

**Query for ,,the latest values of all parameters for all items":**

Code (see explanation [SQL Server get latest value by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203506/sql-server-get-latest-value-by-date)):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
*
FROM #Measurements
ORDER BY row_number() over (partition by ItemID order by MeasurementDate desc)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you please comment about how efficient these db structure and queries are?

Comment: Queries and procedures depend on many things, some of them are even more important than the quality of the code. For example, server performance, chosen DBMS, the configuration, and so on. So, I didn't consider the performance of the code with a very high relevance, but as a kickoff I would say, that this is more than enough for a few hundred, thousand records in each table.